# How do I enlarge the area in which someone can type in the input field?

Tags: html, css

Simple question really. If I use height: 100px the cursor is still starting in the middle of the input box. I'd like to use the entire box with the cursor starting at the top left to make a more intuitive paragraph writing experience.

I'm simply making a form. When I add width: ***px; you can type to the edge of the extended input box however the same doesn't happen for height: ***px;.

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.form {
  margin: 50px 0 100px 0;
}

.form>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-box {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.text-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-kart {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.main-engine {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.cat {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.description>input {
  width: 500px;
}

.sub-m {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.desc-box {
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <label class="sub-m" for="Sub">Subject</label>
  <input class="form-box" type="text" id="Sub" maxlength="95" required>
  <label for="text-box">Description</label>
  <input type="text" id="text-box" class="desc-box" maxlength="200" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `<input type="text">` instead of `<textarea>`?

Comment: Can I ask you why aren't you using a `<textarea>` instead of a simple `<input>`?

Comment: Because I'm new and still learning. ANY advice or teachings are welcome!

Comment: @Maximilian Then you should take a look at the [textarea](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) HTML tag =)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t change input control’s height. If you want paragraph writing experience use textarea html tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want multi-line support, like a paragraph, use [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead of `<input type="text">`. An `<input>` will only give you a single line.

You can set a default height of an `<textarea>` with the `rows` attribute or set a `min-height` via CSS.

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  /* min-height: 150px; */
}
```

```html
<textarea name="comments" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead of an `input`. This is a multi-line plain-text editing control.

Here is your code updated with a `textarea`:

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

textarea {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 10px;
  width: 500px;
}

.form  {
  margin: 50px 0 100px 0;
}

.form > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-box  {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.text-box  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-kart  {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.main-engine  {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.cat  {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}

.description  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.description > input {
  width: 500px;
}

.sub-m {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.desc-box  {
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <label class="sub-m" for="Sub">Subject</label>
  <input class="form-box" type="text" id="Sub" maxlength="95" required>
  <label for="text-box">Description</label>
  <textarea type="text" id="text-box" class="desc-box" maxlength="200" required>
  </textarea>
</div>
```